# How to insert data into a table and get value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on an assignment that requires SQL statements. The assignment is about an online shopping cart.

I have 3 tables:

- Product
- LineItem
- Invoice

The user clicks add to cart button, and I have to store the data into the Invoice table and each item with the quantity into the LineItem table. The problem is when I insert the data into the Invoice table, how do I know what Invoice number the data is being inserted into? Because I have to insert data into LineItem table with the same invoice number.

Note: Invoice Number is an auto-generated field.

Comment: You'll know because you've retrieved it or generated it somehow. There's not enough information in you question to know how you do that.

Comment: It's an auto incrementing field

Comment: Then you can refer to it after you've inserted an invoice by referencing `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I have no idea how to code that. I mean creating a procedure or...

Comment: I don't know - you're the one who posed the question. I assume your assignment gies you some pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using a `Stored Procedure` there are two basic methods:
 1. right after the `INSERT`into Invoice use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`
 2. use the `INSERT` with the `OUTPOUT` clause

---

after comment.

in the Stored Procedure:

```
DECLARE @Scope_Ident INT
INSERT [Table] ()
VALUES ()

SET @Scope_Ident = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

if then you need return the `ID` to the application do:

```
SELECT @Scope_Ident
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how can I use SCOPE_IDENTITY()? I tried that and it gave me an error

Comment: @Jack next time give details of the error.

Comment: Sorry, it was a syntax error like red underlined. I am actually trying this and I will let you know soon. Thank you so much for you help

Comment: I know this will work but I am trying to do something and might take me a while. Thanks for your help